# How to use user.username in templates Django 2.1

Tags: django

I wan to to have delete anchor which is shown or hide on condition however delete anchor is invisible.

**detail.html**

```
{% if user.username == obj.con_id %}
<a href="{% url 'consignment:delete' obj.id %}">delete</a>
{% endif %}
```

I checked in the template, I could see the values

```
{{user.username}}  --> user1
{{obj.con_id}} --> user1
```

here is my views,models

**views.py**

```
def congsignmentDetail(request,detail_id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(ConsignmentInfo,id=detail_id)
    return render(request,'consignment/detail.html',{'obj':obj})
```

**models.py**

```
class ConsignmentInfo(models.Model):
    con_id = models.Foreignkey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj.con_id` in your code is a `User` object, not a string.  So you should compare two objects like this:

```
{% if user == obj.con_id %}
```

Comment: really really thank u!!!! .thank you sincerely. T.T  This caused me to wander for hours.